# Execute p.sendMessage only once in PlayerMoveEvent

Tags: java, bukkit

When the playerMoveEvent executes it sends a cancel message every time he walks. Would it be possible to only send it once?

Here's the main class:

```
package me.mortadelle2.togglePVP;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class PVP extends JavaPlugin{

    public int turnOn;
    public int turnOff;

    ArrayList<String> noPVP = new ArrayList<String>();

    HashMap<String, Integer> stepCounter = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public void onEnable(){
        new MainEvents(this);
        getLogger().info("You may now toggle PVP!");
    }

    public void onDisable(){
        getLogger().info("You may no longer toggle PVP ;(");
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

    final Player p = (Player) sender;

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("pvp") && p.hasPermission("togglepvp.toggle")){

            if (args.length == 0){
                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Invalid usage! /pvp [on or off]");
                return true;
            }

            if (args.length == 1){

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("on")){

                    stepCounter.put(p.getName(), 0);

                    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "PVP " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "will be turned on in 5 seconds! Don't move!");

                    turnOn = this.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {



                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            noPVP.remove(p.getName());
                            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "PVP" + ChatColor.YELLOW + " has been turned on!");

                        }
                    }, 100L);
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("off") && p.hasPermission("togglepvp.toggle")) {

                    stepCounter.put(p.getName(), 0);

                    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "PVP " + ChatColor.YELLOW
                            + "will be turned off in 5 seconds! Don't move!");

                    turnOff = this.getServer().getScheduler()
                            .scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    noPVP.add(p.getName());
                                    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "PVP"
                                            + ChatColor.YELLOW
                                            + " has been turned off!");

                                }
                            }, 100L);
                    return true;
                }

            }

        }


        return false;
    }

}
```

And the Listener class:

```
package me.mortadelle2.togglePVP;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDamageByEntityEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerMoveEvent;

public class MainEvents implements Listener {

    PVP getter;

    public MainEvents(PVP plugin){

        plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);

        this.getter = plugin;

    }

    @EventHandler
    public void playerDamagesWhenToggledOff(EntityDamageByEntityEvent e){

        Player victim = (Player) e.getEntity();
        Player damager = (Player) e.getDamager();

        if (getter.noPVP.contains(victim) || getter.noPVP.contains(damager)){
            e.setCancelled(true);
        }

    }

    @EventHandler
    public void playerMovesSoCancelsTask(PlayerMoveEvent e){
        Player p = e.getPlayer();

        getter.stepCounter.put(p.getName(), 1);

        if (getter.stepCounter.get(p.getName()) == 1){

        if (e.getTo().getBlockX() != e.getFrom().getBlockX() || e.getTo().getBlockY() != e.getFrom().getBlockY()
                || e.getTo().getBlockZ() != e.getFrom().getBlockZ()){

            getter.getServer().getScheduler().cancelTask(getter.turnOn);
            getter.getServer().getScheduler().cancelTask(getter.turnOff);
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You moved so the action was cancelled!");

            getter.stepCounter.put(p.getName(), 0);
        }
        }

    }

}
```

I tried counting his steps and incrementing when he walks, but that doesn't work, so I can't imagine what will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start by deleting all the global variables you have, and then make one public static ArrayList for holding all the players that have enabled pvp protection and one for those who are waiting to change states.

```
public static ArrayList<String> noPVP = new ArrayList<String>();//Holds players that have pvp protection enabled
public static ArrayList<String> playersWaiting = new ArrayList<String>();//Holds players waiting to change states
```

The static modifier will create an object you can access throughout classes without having to have a 'getter' instance of your main class by doing PVP.[var]. You can remove all your other global variables, and now since these variables are static you can remove the getter in your listener class.

To fix your problem your going to need to modify your command to put the player in the map when they execute the command

```
if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("on")) {
    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "PVP will be turned on in 5 seconds! Don't move!");
    playersWaiting.add(player.getName());

    Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (playersWaiting.contains(player.getName())) {
                playersWaiting.remove(player.getName());
                noPVP.remove(player.getName());
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "You have turned PVP on!");
            }
        }
    }, 100L);
    return true;
} else if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("off")) {
    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "PVP will be turned off in 5 seconds. Don't move!");
    playersWaiting.add(player.getName());

    this.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (playersWaiting.contains(player.getName())) {
                playersWaiting.remove(player.getName());
                noPVP.add(player.getName());
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "You have turned PVP off!");
            }
        }
    }, 100L);
    return true;
}
```

Your player move event should remove the player from the map entirely if they change locations:

```
@EventHandler
public void playerMovesSoCancelsTask(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
    Player player = e.getPlayer();//Get the player

    //Check if the player is moving to a new block
    if (e.getTo().getBlockX() != e.getFrom().getBlockX() || e.getTo().getBlockY() != e.getFrom().getBlockY() || e.getTo().getBlockZ() != e.getFrom().getBlockZ()) {

        //Check if the player is waiting to turn on/off pvp
        if (PVP.playersWaiting.contains(player.getName())) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You moved so the action was cancelled!");
            PVP.playersWaiting.remove(player.getName()); //Remove the player from the waiting list
        }
    }
}
```

A few other problems that i noticed:

1) You cast CommandSender to player without any checks. Try executing the command from the console and see what happens. A google search should tell you how to fix that.

2) In your `playerDamagesWhenToggledOff` method of your listener your checking the player itself, not their name. Be sure to use their name: `if (Main.noPVP.containsKey(victim.getName())) { e.setCancelled() }`

3) You never remove the players from the variables, make sure you make a new `PlayerQuitEvent` and remove the player from all the global variables.